# Passing drop down list option to controller

Tags: html, model-view-controller

I have a drop down list in the form of the select tag as shown below:

```
<select id = "1">
<option>Amy</option>
<option>Gi-Anne</option>
</select>
```

I want to pass the selected option - either Amy or Gi Anne to this method of the controller.

```
public String name (string nameSelected)
{
    var query = new NameQuery();
    if(nameSelected.Equals('Amy')) 
    {run a specific query}
else if(nameSelected.Equals('Gi-Anne')) 
        {run a specific query}

}
```

How do I pass the parameter of the selected drop down list value to the controller? Appreciate your help and thanks in advance.

Comment: Which MVC framework are you using (asp.net mvc)? Are you submitting a form (in which case your select tag needs a `name` attribute - `<select name="nameSelected">` or are you posting using ajax?

Answer (score 0):

This is 'fairly' easy using [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/), see this [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/vYE9dw4d4IrDy7aRlznG?p=preview) for a (simulated) example.

The HTML changes to this:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="myController">
  State: {{onChangeText}}
  <br/>
  <select ng-model="selectedItemId" id="itemList" ng-change="onChange()">
    <option value="{{item.id}}" ng-selected="{{item.id == selectedItemId}}" ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.name}}</option>
  </select>
  <br/>
  {{selectedQuery}}
</div>
</body>
```

With a controller like this:

```
app.controller("myController", [
      "$scope",
      "$http",
      function($scope, $http){
        var self = {};

        self.simulatedGetQuery = function() {
          console.log($scope.selectedItemId);
          $scope.selectedQuery = "";

          switch($scope.selectedItemId) {
            case "1":
              $scope.selectedQuery = "Query Amy";
              break;
            case "2":
              $scope.selectedQuery = "Query Gi-Anne";
              break;
          }
        };

        self.httpGetQuery = function() {
          $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'http://somehostname/action/' + $scope.selectedItemId
          }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            $scope.selectedQuery = response;
          }, function errorCallback(response) {
          });
        };

        // -- SCOPED -- //

        $scope.selectedItemId = 0;

        $scope.items = [
          {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Amy"
          },
          {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "Gi-Anne"
          }
        ];

        $scope.onChange = function() {
          $scope.onChangeText = "simulated GET triggered.";

          self.simulatedGetQuery();

          // Use this for actual GET
          // self.httpGetQuery
        };


        // --- //

        $scope.onChangeText = "waiting for user input";
        $scope.selectedQuery = "no query selected. Chose a person for a valid query.";
      }]);
```

It would need to be fleshed out in a real environment, but I think it will do for a simulated test. Check the scripts in the Plunk for a more detailed perspective on how to do this. All of this is clientside.

The URL of the `$http` call would be to your backend (MVC or Web API) controller.